# v-on:model="form.email" expects a function value, got undefined

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js 2 - I am trying to bind form inputs but I always get the erro message ( on all inputs ..)

```
v-on:model="form.email" expects a function value, got undefined


                        <form id="registrationForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" @model="form.email" placeholder="enter your email address">
                            </div>
                            <button @click="sendRegistration" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-gradient submit">SEND</button>
                        </form>
```

and the script

```
 data: function() {
    return {
        form: {
            ...
            email: '',
            ...
        }
      }
  },
  methods: {
    sendRegistration: function() {
        console.log('sending form')
        return false
    }
},
```

Comment: Use `v-model="form.email"`. You're trying to create an event handler called model using the '@' character. Events need to use functions (which isn't what you want to do in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting some things mixed up. Attributes starting with [`v-on:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on), often abbreviated as `@`, are used to register event listeners on elements. `@click="sendRegistration"` will for example register the `sendRegistration` method defined on your `Vue` instance as a handler for that element's `click` event.

What you're trying to accomplish has nothing to do with event handling. The attribute you need is called [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) and binds an `<input>`'s value to a value saved on your `Vue` instance.

---

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" @model="form.email">
```

should be

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" v-model="form.email">
```